# Python selenium, execute_script always returns the error that the variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, automation, browser-automation

> lets say my javascript.js file has a variable named hi which has the value 69 and I execute that using selenium

```
driver.execute_script(open("javascript.js").read())
```

> And now I wanna print it using console.log

```
driver.execute_script("console.log(hi);")
```

> it will return the error that hi is not defined, even if it is outside the function, plz help

Comment: what is the use case ?

Comment: @cruisepandey i was automating a website to do stuff and that needs javascript too, so i need to use javascript,

Comment: Could you show some more of the js code? Is `hi` assigned and accessed correctly?

Comment: @axtck  It is a function, but the same thing happens with a variable
'var gbppd = (function (){
    let book = document.getElementById("viewport");
    let observer = null;
    let links = [];
    let targets = [];'

Comment: @axtck it works on the browser console so i guess its not a problem with the assignment

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience using Selenium, but I will take a look, let me know if u find something

Comment: Is the path to your js file correct? if it is in the same folder, you could try `driver.execute_script(open("./javascript.js").read())`

Comment: @axtck nope
`browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
browser.execute_script(open("./javascript.js").read())
time.sleep(3)
browser.execute_script("gbppd.start()")`
error:
**selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: gbppd is not defined**